# Microsoft Graph API: Get Attendees or Participants from a ongoing Teams Meeting

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, spfx

I am using Microsoft Graph API to create online meetings and that is working fine. Is there any way to track and monitor the participants or Attendees of the ongoing Teams meeting? I tried to use the attendeeReport endpoint of the Graph API but it gives back the results once the Meeting is concluded or the Attendee leaves the meeting. I want to fetch the real-time data of the participants attending the meeting.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onlinemeeting?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: As per my knowledge, we do not have any such API to get the real-time data of the participants attending the meeting.
I will check it once internally and let you know.

Comment: Could you please try with below GRAPI API:   Fetch attendee report of a live event
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-4-fetch-attendee-report-of-a-live-event

Answer (score 0):

There is no such API available to get attendees or participants from an ongoing Teams Meeting